# Sails view structure

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

Hi I created a sails app completely for api using. It doesn't has a view file, now I have a html, css, js directory structure, which I want to show as a front page of my app. My html directory structure is following.

```
   +-ApiDocumentationApp
    |
    -script
    |
    -css
    |
    -images
    |
    --index.html
```

Now I don't want to use any templating engine like jade or ejs. Also I don't want to change the directory structure to sailsjs', asset and view system. Is there any way I can do it inside sailsjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever your reluctance may be, by far the easiest solution here is to place all of your assets (`scripts`, `css`, `images` and `index.html`) under the `/assets` folder of your Sails app, and remove the default `/` route in `/config/routes.js`.  Then your `index.html` file will be served up by Sails by default.

The alternative would be to modify the default `Gruntfile.js` (in Sails v0.9.x) or the individual Grunt tasks under `/tasks/config` (in Sails v0.10.x) to point directly to your top-level asset folders and files rather than `./assets`.  It's do-able, but error prone and less sustainable!